# Service Fabric for Development Environment on Windows Server

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

We are developing Microservices with .NET Core on top of Service Fabric.

We have two development environments that is part of our release process, Automated Test Environment and Functional Test Environment. Using two full instances of SF on Azure is costy given that we can tolerate availability and performance for our dev environment and given that our production environment is on Azure. We already have a VM that we can use.

- Does SF work under Windows Server 2016 Core? (I couldn't find any affirmation online).
- Is it possible to have two instances of our application running on one VM?

Comment: Instances of your application run under the same SF cluster. Is that what you're after or are you asking if you can run 2 clusters on the same VM? I'd think you'd want 2 VMs for that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to setup a Service Fabric cluster you need at **least 3 machines** (or you cannot reach quorum in your cluster). If you run it on Azure then you also choose the Reliability and durability tier for your nodetypes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#the-reliability-characteristics-of-the-cluster. A higher reliability tier (Silver, Gold or Platinum) means that you need further nodes (machines) in cluster.

You can run multiple instances of the same application and of different deployment versions in the same cluster. You need to consider how your services are assigned ports (for those that expose HTTP endpoints), otherwise these will conflict if you have multiple instances of the same application type in the same cluster. There is currently no way to provision new instances through Visual Studio, you need to use PowerShell, the API or the Service Fabric Explorer.

Comment: Currently Windows Server 2016 Core is not supported, this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-anywhere lists the supported OS versions for Windows Server. (There is also a comment in that article from a person who tried, and failed, to set it up on Core)